# even square numbers represented as two primes added together

Tags: number-theory

Can every even square number be written as the sum of 2 prime numbers? How do you prove the result?

Comment: $0$ can't.  Other than that, the answer is almost certainly yes, but I don't know of any reason why this special case of Goldbach's conjecture should be any easier than the general case.

Comment: If we permute the words and ask which primes can be written as the sum of two squares, the question is much more tractable ...

Comment: I agree with @Robert; and must ask, why are you upvoting a guy which has done no research, besides copying and un-generalizing a widely known conjecture? If I ask the same about even triangular numbers, or Fibonacci numbers, will you upvote me too?